# How do I store input values into an object?

Tags: java

I am a new programmer trying to make a program with a GUI. I want to input data so that I can input a name, weight, and a height all in text fields. I have gotten this part done with, but I have no idea how to even get these stored with an object.

After pressing a button, I have this code for when the button is pressed

```
ArrayList tempArray = new ArrayList(3);
    tempArray.add(nameInput);
    tempArray.add(heightInput);
    tempArray.add(weightInput);
```

My text field names are stored as nameInput/heightInput/weightInput, but I feel like I am not supposed to use an ArrayList. I also want to be able to create other objects, so I dont want to use a type of storage that cannot be replaced. Sorry if I couldnt explain that well because Im very new to this, but help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should have to use the ArrayList either if you have an object meant to hold these values. However, how you build the object with these values is somewhat up to you. It depends on what the object is that you're storing the values in, and how you plan on structuring that object. For instance, you could potentially pass all of these values into the object via a constructor like so:

```
ExampleObject eo = new ExampleObject(nameInput, heightInput, weightInput);
```

You can also declare a new object and then use setters to put these values into that object like this:

```
ExampleObject eo = new ExampleObject();
eo.setName(nameInput);
eo.setHeight(heightInput);
eo.setWeight(weightInput);
```

It really depends how you build your object.

Comment: This answers part of it, thank you! However, what if I want to make multiple different people, up to an unlimited number? Because my project will let many profiles be made so I need an automatic way of making new objects if that makes sense.

Comment: @rainer's answer somewhat touches on this. If you're trying to store a bunch of different `People` objects, you're going to need to either set up a database, or some other form of persistence (could be XML, JSON, etc.). If you truly want the potential to be 'unlimited' though, you're probably looking for a database solution. However, that's something that you'll have to do some research for on your own. Maybe consider starting [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-create-database.htm)?

Comment: Oh okay, Ill check that out. Thank you, I appreciate the help!

Comment: No problem. As an aside, I feel as though everyone who posted on this question contributed something that helped you out. I'd suggest considering upvoting the answers as a show of kindness and accepting the one that helped you out the most so that your question doesn't appear unanswered.

Comment: i already have upvoted all of them but because I dont have 15 points or something they wont be shown publicly. I think you answered my question well though, so I gave that check thing to you :)

Comment: My apologies. I forgot about that caveat when you're a newcomer. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object by first defining a class (titled 'person' or whatever) as follows:

```
class Person {

    // Instance variables.
    String name;
    double weight, height;

    public Person(String pName, double pWeight, double pHeight) {
        this.name = pName;
        this.weight = pWeight;
        this.height = pHeight;  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // To create an object of type Person.
        Person p = new Person("Alice", 70, 170);
        // Or in your case.
        Person q = new Person(nameInput, weightInput, heightInput);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This would work i think, but what if I want to make multiple profiles of people? Thats what I am aiming for but I dont know how I would be able to make multiple people with this method

Comment: Do you want to your object to hold info on multiple people or do you just need a collection of people. For the latter, you could use: `List<Person> listOfPeople = new ArrayList<>();` and you can keep adding individual 'Person' objects to this collection which you can later iterate over. For the former, I suggest creating a new object that holds the above-mentioned ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the question is what do you want to do with the data you collect. 
An ArrayList is appropriate when the data storage isn't permanent and you want to iterate through the list, for example. 
If you want to store the data permanently, you should consider using a database, like MySQL.
What do you want to do with the data? What is your project about?

Comment: Yes, the data will not be permanent from what I understand, but I could be interpreting what youre saying wrong.

Im making a program where you input data (Name, weight, and height), and then that makes a person a profile and you are able to edit different peoples profiles and possibly change their weight. Its just a part of my whole project, but this is the part I am working on right now.

Answer (score 1):

In object oriented programming consider an object and it's definition and when you are trying to store multiple objects of the same type then you add a collection on top of it. Try to use MVC when implementing something like this, so you can get clear readable code and segregated views, models and controller logic. Makes it easy to understand. Draw it on a paper on what you want first then identify the Objects and screens and models, then you can start writing the code, which would probably take very less time once you have everything clear on a piece of paper.

```
class Person {
    String id;
    String name;
    ....
}

PersonModel {
     Map<String, Person> collectionOfPersons = new HashMap<String, Person>();
     Person getPersonById(String id);
     void addPerson(Person person);
     void removePerson(Person person);
     void updatePerson(Person person);
}
```

You use PersonModel as your dataSource for your View, this way you can show list of all persons in a list in the UI, which allows you to perform operations like add, remove, update. 
When you are creating a new person the UI would be blank.
When you are updating existing user the UI would be populated with the current values of the person based on id.
When you are deleting the user the UI corresponding to the Person should not be visible.

So on and so forth.

Hope this helps.